# Combining Multiple Dictionaries (from json file)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem I’ve been trying to fix, but I haven’t found the right way to do it.

I have around 60-70 pages of data from an api, in json form. I need to convert these to a list and combine one of the values.

The format of the data is as follows:

`{"success":true,otherData:0,neededData:[{moreData:0,data:1},{moreData:1,data:0}]}`

And as I said, I have about 60-70 of those at a time.

What I am looking for in the end is a list like this:

`[{moreData:0,data:1},{moreData:1,data:0}]`

including all the data across the lists.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your desired result isn't a valid dictionary, it doesn't have any keys.

Comment: We don't have enough information here.  Is the json data a list of examples like the one you gave?

Comment: Meant list, not dictionary. Sorry!

Comment: James - All the json data is formatted like my example, and all the data I need combined is under the ‘neededData’ key

Comment: Have you tried using a list comprehension expression? `[x for d in data for x in d.get('neededData', [])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are continually getting responses in that format as a json string
in Python 3.x ish

```
import json
# global variable just for example
results = []

# assume you pass each successful request into this function
# @ param res : valid json string
def process_response(res):
    global results
    # loads returns a dict object
    res_dict = json.loads(res)
    results += res_dict.get('neededData', [])
```

This will work, and continue to update your results array with the items from needed data

Some testing:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a
[3]
>>> a += b
>>> a
[3, 1, 2]
>>> a += []
>>> a 
[3, 1, 2]   # no change
>>> a += [5,6]
>>> a
[3, 1, 2, 5, 6]

>>> jst = '{ "l": [{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b": 4}], "v": "other"}'
>>> json.loads(jst)
{'l': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}], 'v': 'other'}
>>> type(json.loads(jst))
<class 'dict'>
>>> json.loads(jst).get('l', [])
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

Comment: Hey halfer, sorry about that. I'll remove it from my answer

Answer (score 0):

if your original piece of data looks like this:

```py
dataset = { 
    "success":True,
    "otherData":0,
    "neededData":[
        {"moreData":0,"data":1},
        {"moreData":1,"data":0}
    ]
}
```

Then you can just access the "needed data" with `dataset['neededData']`,
or `dataset.get('neededData', list())` in the case that the needed data isn't always there. At least, based on your original example.

---

If you have multiple request responses with data in that shape, you can aggregate them together with something more along the following lines:

```py
dataset = [item for itemlist in responses for item in itemlist.get("neededData", [])]
```

which is roughly equivalent to:

```py
dataset = []
for itemlist in responses:
    for item in itemlist.get("neededData", []):
        dataset.append(item)
```

Comment: He has 60-70 responses like this, he wants to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the result list from each API response.

```
all_data = []
for res in api_results:
    all_data.extend(res.neededData)
```